# What is the typical equipment/clothing for a Soul Reaper?

Tags: bleach

As the title says, I'm interested in what the typical equipment is for a Soul Reaper and if there is any difference in equipment...

- ... they have when operating in the World of the Living as opposed to operating in the Soul Society
- ... between regular Soul Reapers, Seated Officers, Lieutenants and Captains

I'd like to see actual names if they exists rather than generalized named. For instance, while the white jacket that a Captain wears on top of their black robe could just be referred to as a Captain's Jacket, if it has a proper name I'd rather that be listed.

I also including clothing as I remember it being mentioned the black robe is actually some sort of protective gear.

Added information/links on the functionality of the piece of equipment is also welcomed (for further reading).

Individual items don't need to be included (i.e. the thing Mayuri Kurotsuchi injected into himself to regrow his arm during his fight with Uryu Ishida during the Rukia Rescue Operation by the Rioka (2nd/3rd season?)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Clothing](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Gotei#Uniforms)

It's actually relatively simple for the "standard shinigami". They will wear:

- a [Shihakushō](http://bleach.neoseeker.com/wiki/Shihakusho) (死覇装, Garment of Dead Souls), the black .. thingy which comprises of:

  - a [white shitagi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shitagi) (下着, under clothing)
  - a [black kosode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosode) (小袖, small sleeve)
  - a [black hakama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakama) (袴, "trousers")
- [white tabi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabi) (足袋, foot pouch / socks)
- and [waraji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waraji) (草鞋, sandals)

Additionally the Lieutenants will sometimes wear an armband with the division symbol and number.

The Captains wear a white overcoat called [Haori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimono#Accessories_and_related_garments) (羽織) with their division symbol in a rhombus (the Gotei 13 symbol)

There is differences for the [Covert Ops (隠密機動, Onmitsukidō)](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Onmitsukido) They wear a stereotypical ninja outfit.
The other subdivisions of the Covert Ops (namely Detention Corps and Inner Court Corps) also have different clothing.

## Equipment

Every shinigami has a Zanpakuto of their own. They will always carry them **especially** on duty. Usually they don't carry any further equipment.

Additionally the fourth division (healers) is regularly seen with pouches for medicine and related material.

Furthermore Lieutenants and Captains will automatically be given a Power-Suppression-Sigil when they pass the Senkaimon to go to the World of Living.

Answer (score 0):

You **only** need a Shihakusho [unless you're a Captain and as such there's the jacket that has to be worn over it[. The garment itself doesn't have to be the standard they give you, there are shinigami like Nemu that wear a different style that isn't the default uniform cut. 
Then there's the aesthetic and functional gear that you are allowed to have over the uniform itself which you are allowed to have. This is one of the peculiarities of the Gotei 13, despite their structured organization, the members aren't bound to look the same due to the understanding that each soul and spirit has it's own story behind them.